# SSH 2FA for everyone but the root user | Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, openssh, 2-factor-authentication

I am currently trying to achieve, that the root user can login with only the password, but without the 2FA authentication, when logging in from a specific Host. So far my sshd_config looks like this:

```
#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#Authentication
AllowUsers myuser
ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
AuthenticationMethods keyboard-interactive
#PermitRootLogin no
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
UsePAM yes
MaxAuthTries 3


KexAlgorithms curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256
Ciphers chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
MACs hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256,umac-128@openssh.com


LogLevel VERBOSE


UseDNS yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
HostbasedAuthentication no
X11Forwarding no
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL
#Banner /etc/ssh/banner

#SFTP
#Subsystem sftp  /usr/lib/ssh/sftp-server -f AUTHPRIV -l INFO

Match Address 100.100.100.100
  PermitRootLogin yes
```

However, this didn't work, the password is being prompted over and over again. So after a bit of research, I adapted my /etc/pam.d/sshd (I made a group noauth and added the root user to it)

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth       required     pam_sepermit.so
auth       substack     password-auth
auth       include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-auth      optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
account    required     pam_nologin.so
account    include      password-auth
password   include      password-auth
# pam_selinux.so close should be the first session rule
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
# pam_selinux.so open should only be followed by sessions to be executed in the user context
session    required     pam_selinux.so open env_params
session    required     pam_namespace.so
session    optional     pam_keyinit.so force revoke
session    include      password-auth
session    include      postlogin
# Used with polkit to reauthorize users in remote sessions
-session   optional     pam_reauthorize.so prepare
auth [success=done default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup noauth
auth required pam_google_authenticator.so echo_verification_code
```

But sadly, nothing changed, I still can't login with the root user. I can't add nullok to the google pam module, because everyone else has to be forced to use 2FA authentication

Help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

I resloved my issue (kind of): I added nullok to the pam module, and also a short script, to /etc/profile (so it applies globally), that enforces every user to have a 2FA set up (except for the root user). If anyone is interested, this is the script:

```
if [ ! -f "$HOME"/.google_authenticator ]; then
    if [ ! "$USER" = "root" ]; then
        google-authenticator -t -d -f -r 3 -R 30 -W
        echo "Please scan the above QR-Code with your 2FA App, or copy the given link. Otherwise, you can no longer log in via SSH"
    fi
fi
```